# Template For Detail View

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to IOS programming and trying to create a detail view when you tap a cell in a table. I have no clue how to go about this. I do know how to create the segue from the table to the new view, although I'm not sure how to make the view show the details. Do I need a template, how would I go about this?

Thanks Curlip

Answer (score 0):

A detail view is actually relatively simple. For a simple page to display information, you will probably want to use a UIViewController.

To use one, you will need to have a UIViewController class for your detail view, which you will then link to an interface (on storyboard or in a xib file).

You can then transition to the detail view from your UITableViewController by overriding the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

Edit:
Here is a nice tutorial to use if you get stuck. It is 3 parts. Part 1 goes over creating a UITableView. Part 2 goes over a detail view.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, if i get any trouble I will report back.

Comment: For a new developer, I would definitely recommend the website http://www.raywenderlich.com/ for iOS development tutorials.

Check the edit of my post for a nice tutorial to start on :~)